# Structtype definition for the nested Json file in pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark-sql

I have the json file for which I have created a dataframe in pyspark.

Here is the json file content:

```
{"xyz": [ {"c1": "a", "c2": "b", "c3": "d"}]}
```

Here is the Structype schema that I have created.

```
schema = StructType([
StructField("abc",ArrayType(
StructType([
StructField("c1",StringType()),
StructField("c2",StringType()),
StructField("c3",StringType())])))])
```

```

````
rdd = sc.textFile(path).map(lambda x: x.encode("ascii", "ignore")).map(lambda line: json.loads(line))
df = rdd.toDF(schema=schema)`

df_colsexp = df.select(
col('cards.c1').alias('c1'),
col('cards.c2').alias('c2'),
col('cards.c3').alias('c3')
)
df_colsexp.show(5,False)`

df_colsexp.printSchema()

```
>>> df_colsexp.printSchema()                                                                                                                                                      
root                                                                                                                                                                              
 |-- c1: array (nullable = true)                                                                                                                                                  
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)                                                                                                                                   
 |-- c2: array (nullable = true)                                                                                                                                     
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)                                                                                                                                   
 |-- c3: array (nullable = true)                                                                                                                                          
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)                                                                                                                                   


df_colsexp.show(5,False)

Output:
c1   c2  c3
[a] [b] [c]
````

My question is why c1,c2,c3 columns are shown as array in the output?
How can make these columns c1,c2,c3 as a Stringtype? 
So that in the output those square brackets will go away. ?